# No jala el ID del GET en la consulta, NO APARECE NADA

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
QUIERO LLEVAR LOS DATOS DE califica1 a a1, califica2 a a2, califica3 a a3, califica4 a a4, pero el ID DEL GET NO ME FUNCINA, COMO LOS PUEDO EXTRAER

Comment: podrias publicar el archivo que manda llamar a demoraphael.php?

Comment: <td><?php echo '<a href="./graf/demoraphael.php?Id='.$rows['id'].'">VER</a>';?></td>

Comment: ya vi porque no funcional el id es porque el numero es decimal,

Comment: seria ideal que quitaras la imagen y colocaras el código